# 99.99% durability. What does it mean?

Tags: amazon-s3, durability

Amazon S3 offers two plans:

> Storage
>   (Designed for 99.999999999% Durability)

and

> Reduced Redundancy Storage 
>   (Designed for 99.99% Durability)

Designed to provide 99.999999999% durability and 99.99% availability of objects over a given year.

[Heres the link](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/#protecting)

So if I have 10 000 files I can expect to loose one in average with the second plan per year? am I interpreting that correctly?

Edit: Maby I have to put it more clearly:

How do you interpret especially the "designed for" part. If for example offer 99,9% availability I guarantee that and pay a penal for every hour more or something like that.
But if I design the system for 99,9% availability, I choose the parts with the knowledge that the system will probably have a downtime of 0.1% on statistical average.

That does not necessarily mean that I guarantee anything. Its just what the system is designed for...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

RRS will survive the total loss of one data centre, as well using multiple drives, etc. Regular S3 storage will survive the loss of two.

The 99.999999999% durability figure is a bit pointless - they're quoting something less than the the probability of a K/T event sized comet hitting Earth, and if that happened we wouldn't be worrying about our S3 data.

The probability of a political or economic event taking down Amazon is a much higher than the risk of three AWS regions being simultaneously destroyed, so I reject that notion that data in S3 "doesn't need to be backed up" although it is good to know that the system has been designed to survive most eventualities.

The risk of having a system you have connected to your AWS account compromised, and losing data that way, is higher again, so **always keep offline backups**.

Comment: exactly what i wanted to hear but not what i asked for :D

Comment: it's hard if your data size greater than 100tb+

Comment: "... if that happened we wouldn't be worrying about our S3 data.". lol, but good point:)

Comment: There is a critically relevant distinction between regions and data centers. And that isn't the only major flaw in this answer. Eleven nines doesn't refer to the likelihood that you'll lose 100% of your data (that is higher than 1e-11 per year, practically speaking). The durability figure means that the more data you've stored (and the longer you store it), the more likely it is that you will lose _some_ of it. So an extinction event is not necessarily the most likely outcome. The philosophy and the backup recommendation I agree with, but the factual content is lacking in accuracy.

Answer (score 11):

Amazon has provided an example of what this means in their FAQ:

http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#How_durable_is_Amazon_S3

> **Q: How durable is Amazon S3?**
>
> Amazon S3 is designed to provide 99.999999999% durability of objects over a given year. This durability level corresponds to an average annual expected loss of 0.000000001% of objects. For example, if you store 10,000 objects with Amazon S3, you can on average expect to incur a loss of a single object once every 10,000,000 years. In addition, Amazon S3 is designed to sustain the concurrent loss of data in two facilities.